# How to disable ESlint parser error messages in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I have ESlint configured with vscode using the plugin, now I'm wondering is there some way I can stop ESlint from showing me the parser/syntax errors, so I can instead view the syntax errors that the Salsa language service provides by default.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**Update**: please refer [this updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65268582/1906088)

Open up settings.json and add the property:
`"eslint.enable": false`

Check:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Comment: is there any way to disable just few rules rather than the whole eslint?

Comment: @SirajAlam I don't think you can do that with VS Code settings, you would have to configure your .eslintrc file to disable specific rules. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: this warning is shown **This setting is deprecated. Disable ESLint using the extensions viewlet.**

Comment: @AwaisNasir definately agree. Only melMass updated their answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65268582/1906088 and it needs to be appreciated cause it's the only one up to date for this one at the moment.

Answer (score 33):

The old:

```json
"eslint.enable": false
```

Is deprecated, now you need to use the builtin VSCode mechanism for disabling extensions:

[image: vscode-screenshot]

Answer (score 29):

In order to **disable ESLint only for a specific repo** (instead of disabling it globally). Create `.vscode` folder in your project root and there create a `settings.json` then add the following config:

```
{
    "eslint.enable": false
}
```

Maybe after this setting you should consider adding the `.vscode/settings.json` line to your `.gitignore` file too, but it is based on your dev team's preference.
}

Additionally **if you'd like to ignore only some vendor/3PP `.js` files only** then you should consider creating an `.eslintignore` file. Read more about this [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories).

Comment: People coming here in 2021 and later: this solution is now deprecated [or so said the warning message I got]

Comment: This solution may be deprecated, but at least works, contrary to others.

Answer (score 24):

go to File => Preferences => Settings

[image]

go to Extensions=>ESLint

[image]

**Uncheck** the EsLint:Enable

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In VSCode, go to

```
File >> preferences >> settings
```

Type **'eslint quiet'** in the search bar and click
the check box for quiet mode.

In quiet mode, eslint would ignore basic errors.
This should work for many VSCode users as at March 4, 2022.
You're welcome!

Comment: To be more precise, the **Quiet** setting ignores _warnings_ in the VSC UI.

Answer (score 3):

```
1-) npm install -g eslint
2-) Open up settings.json and add the property: "eslint.enable": false
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable eslint errors in VSCode, Go to `settings.json` and disable all rules like this

```
   "eslint.rules.customizations": [
    {
        "rule": "*",
        "severity": "off"
    }
]
```

This will disable all the eslint rules for you. If you want to disable a particular rule like "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias", you can do the following

```
"eslint.rules.customizations": [
        {
            "rule": "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias",
            "severity": "off"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer in case user doesn't want to disable ESlint totally, but wants to keep ESlint formatting while saving file, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Please open settings.json file and edit the configuration as below:

```
"eslint.enable": false
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @SethFalco Are you sure it fixes automatically the eslint errors ? I do not have that behavior on my side

Comment: The answer has changed since I commented on it. The original version of this (see edit history) had an entirely different answer. I'll delete my comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why some answers states that `eslint.enable` is depracted. it works for me. in my WorkSpace settings (JSON), I add the following configuration and eslint errors disapears

```
{
    ...

    "settings": {
        "eslint.enable": false
    },
}
```