# bracket issue use prettier with eslint

Tags: eslint, prettier

I use prettier with eslint in vs code as follow setting.

```
//.eslintrc
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "root": true,
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": 0
  }
}
```

```
//.prettierc
{
  "printWidth": 100,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": true
}
```

but some eslint recommend conflict autoformatting from prettier.

prettier make code like this.

```
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
```

(autosaving)

```
import {
  mapGetters,
  mapActions
} from 'vuex'
```

but now eslint draw red line.

```
// example
Replace `␍⏎··mapActions,␍⏎··mapGetters␍⏎` with `·mapActions,·mapGetters·`eslint(prettier/prettier)
```

I don't want eslint red line anywhere...

so I was found some document, but cannot found prettier setting..

how disable this red line?

Comment: What is the error shown by eslint? I think you might've missed a semicolon and a comma in the end since you're using airbnb syntax.

Comment: @Sammy Thanks! this is other code, but same issue.
```
Replace `␍⏎··ReqRegist·as·defualt␍⏎` with `·ReqRegist·as·defualt·`eslint(prettier/prettier)```
```

Comment: The other error you've posted is uncleared. Post your full code and where the error is popping if possible.

Comment: edit error msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since prettier is very opinionated, it might cause trouble with es-lint sometimes. You might want to use a library like [prettier-eslint](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint)

This will format your code with prettier, then try to fix it with eslint.
You can probably disable the conflicting rules as described in the prettier docs.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/eslint.html

They've mentioned adding

> {   "extends": ["prettier"] }

to your .eslintrc.json might help along with other configuration.

Comment: can i use run time eslint parser or extends?

Comment: I do not understand what you're talking about. Can you give more information about what you want to know?

Comment: I use vue-cli which use runtime eslint and formatting on Save via prettier.

so this case, eslint show red line on VS code. I want handle it.

Comment: Please refer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939042/disable-eslint-parser-error-messages-vscode

Comment: Thanks to your answer, but i want to use together. I will find some way! thanks a lot!

Comment: Having prettier with eslint can cause a few errors in esint. Whenever you find the conflicting rules, you can add it to the .eslintrc file and turn it off. That's the best case

Comment: Yes. Eslint or any linting enforces you and your team to follow the same syntax. It makes code more easy to read and maintain. You can tweak it to your liking or your organisation standard.